# Ternary Operator with two conditionals

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

I have to learn ternary operator but I can ask a question, how to mount `console.log (array)` in ternary operator since it does not compile.

```
   const string3 = (value3, separator) => {
    if (typeof value3 === "string" && typeof value3! = "") {
      constant array = value3.split (separator)
      console.log (array)}
    else {console.log ("error")}
   }
  string3 ('hello how are you', '');
```

Comment: `constant array =` is not valid syntax...

Comment: where is the ternary?

Comment: `! =` is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a variable in an *expression* context, because the proper initialization of a variable must be a standalone statement. So you can't do something like

```
console.log(condition ? const str = 'foo' // ...`
```

You can declare the variable on the previous line instead and abuse the comma operator (not recommended; if you ever had to do something like this, use `if`/`else` instead):

```js
const string3 = (value3, separator) => {
  let arr;
  console.log(typeof value3 === "string" && typeof value3 != "" ?
    (array = value3.split(separator), array) :
    'error'
  );
}
string3('hello how are you', '');
```

Or, in this case, since the split array is going to be passed directly to `console.log`, just don't declare the extra variable:

```js
const string3 = (value3, separator) => {
  let arr;
  console.log(typeof value3 === "string" && typeof value3 != "" ?
    value3.split(separator) :
    'error'
  );
}
string3('hello how are you', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Ternary or "Conditional" operator is a short form of if-else statment which takes some condition and return a value based on that condition.

**Usage:**

```
condition ? <If-expression> : <Else-expression>
```

e.g.

```
const a = (2+2 == 4) ? 'true' : 'false';
console.log(a);
// OR
console.log((2+2 == '4') ? 'true' : 'false');
```

**Your code:**

Some mistakes, you're making

- `constant array = ...` (constant isn't anything, its `const`)
- `...typeof value3! = ""` ***"! ="*** (having space in-between) isn't anything. Logical operators like ==, !=, === must be written without space between characters.

that's why the code isn't getting compiled. Otherwise there is no problem in the code itself. However, you aren't using ternary operator (? & :) anywhere in your code. Here's how you can use it:

```js
const string3 = (value3, separator) =>
      (typeof value3 === "string" && value3 !== "")  // condition
      ? value3.split(separator)                      // if-statment
      : "error"                                      // else-statment

console.log(string3('hello! how are you?', ''));
```

What above code does is that there is a function called `string3` which takes 2 params `value & separator` and it checks for the condition, then returns either ***splitted array*** or **"error"**. And as its written in [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) syntax, it doesn't have to have an explicit return statement. Then in your function call, you're logging the returned value to conosle

[REFERENCE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)